# Remote event receivers Vs Power automate cloud flows

Tags: development, office-365, power-automate, remote-event-receiver, architecture

I am a big fan of remote event receivers as it is a very solid approach to implement business logic for SharePoint online lists/libraries. But recently, each time i start a new project >> customers ask to use Power Automate flows instead of remote event receivers. Since they do not have to pay for hosting the RER and they think Power automate will allow none-IT people to manage their business logic if they are trained, unlike remote event receiver which require a developer with coding skills.

But after using Power Automate for more than 3 years, i found those weaknesses compared to RER:-

1. If we have a complex business logic >> then we will end up having a very complex Flow which will be hard to manage. And we can end up with hundreds of actions and a sequence of steps. For example if i want to define a unique permission for a list item after been added >> and grant all current users Read-Only >> and grant certain users contribute >> i will end up having 6 actions, while in RER this can be done in 4 lines of codes!
2. Power Automate flows, do not allow us to prevent an Insert, update or delete if certain rules did not meet, unlike RER which allow use to control the adding, updating and deleting and prevent them based on our business logic.

so can anyone advice about the RER vs Power automate flows? and are my above 2 points valid?

Thanks

Comment: 2 requests to close this question!!!! I am always confidence that StacKExchnage contain users who do not know what they are doing.. what most important than this discussion !! especially after the helpful reply i got from Rob

Comment: Also it does not make sense to ask to close a question without describing the reason, be brave and show your case..

Comment: so now i have 3 requests to close this question, without having any explanations why it is been requested to close... not sure if any user have the brevity to mention the reasons

Comment: So finally this got closed.. without adding any comment,,, i will repeat my above statement `I am always confidence that StacKExchnage contain users who do not know what they are doing..` and users who closed this question fall under this category (based on my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

I think your points are valid. Remote event receivers are a more robust technology but they are implemented by a framework (the SharePoint add-in model) that Microsoft considers to be legacy.

There was a discussion about the SharePoint add-in model in the Teams chat during the Microsoft 365 Platform Community Call on March 8, 2022. Vesa Juvonen - Principal Program Manager in SharePoint/OneDrive engineering, who is responsible for the developer ecosystem engagement worldwide, including documentation, guidance, sample, and open-source activities hinted at the future of the Add-in model, "... as we have not invested on add-ins for >7 years - as they are considered as legacy tech - we can certainly expect that it's going away sooner or later."

[image]

So I would advise you to use Power Automate rather than remote event receivers because, sooner or later, Microsoft will deprecate the SharePoint add-in model, at which time you'll be forced to switch whether you like it or not.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but this is really a sad news :( .. so what we will do if we are preventing adding & updating item inside RER ? as we can not replicate those using Power Automate.. am i correct?

Comment: but there is a missing thing from Paul's statement. now any SharePoint list and library contain a set of built-in RERs , you can check them by running `Get-PnPEventReceiver -Identity ` on a new list/library.. so not sure if RER are going to be deprecated.. as seems SharePoint online depend on them heavily.. what do you think?

Comment: You are correct, you cannot prevent adding or updating items using Power Automate.

Comment: Remote event receivers are built using the SharePoint add-in model. If the add-in model gets deprecated, that would mean that remote event receivers have been deprecated. 

Microsoft has not made any official announcements on the future of the add-in model, but I expect that it will be going away sooner or later. When it does, you'll have to replace any remote event receivers or other add-ins. That's why my advice is to move away from using them now.

Answer (score 1):

this is a totally valid question. I'll add that Flows often crap out when placed under load - say, if you have dozens or hundreds running at a time. A RER running under even a Basic tier in Azure can handle this easily. Also RERs can be provisioned via automation while I do not think Flows can.

Clients' desire to use Flow make sense because it decouples them from developers and the infrastructure overhead. Also the legacy status of the RER tech will have to factor into your long term plans.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but SharePoint lists and libraries have built-in RERs.. so not sure if Microsoft is planning to re-imperilment those built-in RERs for the lists/librarues to be run as power automate flows.. so this gives me a feeling that RERs are not going to be deprecated..

Comment: Based on my experience in SharePoint for more than 14 years in 2010-2019 & online.. power platform tools such as Power Bi, Power Apps & Power automate allow non-IT people to write simple apps and flows. but when it comes to enterprise scenarios IT people are needed, because Flows will have to make HTTP requests, parse JSON, integrated with external API, build custom connectors.. then when we as IT people implement those enterprise workflows we end up having a long flows which can take minutes to scrolldown on them, while we can write a reliable RER with few lines of code